# publishg my website from my machin into my server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I develop my application on my visual studio 2012 with .net 4

I want to publish this simple website on my windows server 2003 sp2 which already has .net 4 installed.

What should I do?

#### what I have tried

1- go to build

2- go to publish

3- then i am confures which options i have to choose. i have these options:`file system, web deoply, web deploy package , ftp, and epse`

I am sure that I should not use web deploy. But what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like link answers myself, but the answer for your question is mostly depend on how you want the deploy, the configurations of your server, and the privileges that you have over the target destination.

Take some time to read through [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) carefully to go right with your deployment. That is a complete explanation.